# Creating a hyperlink email within a vba created email

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add the hyperlink function to an email address, within an email generated by vba. Any and all help is appreciated as I am extremely new to working with vba.

Further, we are currently performing our annual customer information audit. Would you please complete the attached form and return it to abc@yahoo.com "

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many free online HTML editors available. You can google them and use any one of them to write you email as you please:
http://www.quackit.com/html/online-html-editor/

In the above example you can then click on "Source" to see the HTML source code to generate the email you just "designed".

Now you can use this HTML code in your VBA. Just make sure that you replace any usage of `"` (single quotation mark) with `""` (double quotation mark) when you compose the email string.

Also, make sure to generate a HTML email using `.HTMLBody` as indicated here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171418%28v=office.11%29.aspx